# jQuery: Return object with children

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Given **`var oJQ = $('#foo').children();`**, how would you also include `foo` with the children in the same assignment?

In other words, `oJQ` should be a jQuery object that holds foo's children and foo.

Comment: Sime I don't know why you're trying to edit my question.

Comment: Probably a transmission error in my browser. I initially received only the first sentence and it was all in bold. Sorry about that.

Comment: Ahhh.  Yeah, I originally had it that way and you're right, it didn't look good so I changed it :) +1 for thinking the same

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`andSelf`](http://api.jquery.com/andSelf/):

```
var oJQ = $('#foo').children().andSelf();
```

Comment: bah, I tried `self()`, I just found `andSelf()` in the docs shortly after asking - thx

Comment: @Chevex Relax :) I'm sure he was going to.

Comment: @Chevex: are you talking about lonesomeday or Grigory.  Realize that just because Grigory's is more concise and in the same string, there are still multiple lookups.  Lonesomeday's solution is a little more explicative.

Comment: No I was talking about lonesomeday. lol I'm not trying to convince you of one thing or another, I just thought grigory's looked cleaner. Calm down guys, lol.

Comment: @Chevex, ahhh - but I did select the answer.  I think the whole editing the question ordeal caused it to uncheck.  Do you see it checked now?  I'm open to other answers that anyone thinks is better, I just like to know the reason for it before I select those answers :)

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#foo').children().andSelf()
```

Comment: @patrick Hm... I guess someone expects answers to be more elaborate

Comment: @Šime Vidas - If that's the case (or actually whatever the case), the down-voter should explain. That seems like a petty reason for someone to give a -1.

Comment: Not sure either Jman, perhaps someone saw lonesomeday's answer and then yours (same answer) ... but rest assure I still upvoted you and it was not me.

Answer (score 1):

By combining the selector-by-id with children selector:

```
var ojq = $("#foo,#foo > *");
```

See here for an example:

http://jsfiddle.net/wK3Xz/

Comment: +1 for an alternative, but `andSelf()` is truly what was desired.

Comment: Deleted my last comment. andSelf() actually works, I'm just dumb and did not use the correct syntax. I still think Grigory has the more succinct way to do it though. One selector instead of chaining selector methods.

Comment: I think some benchmarking may be in order, do you wanna do that? :)

Comment: Remember `children()` is different from `contents()`.  `children()` does not include text nodes.  I'm not sure if `#foo > *` includes the nodes or not.

Comment: @vol7ron - No, the `*` doesn't match text nodes.

Comment: @Chevex `#foo, #foo > * ` are two selectors that are just grouped. jQuery still has to put both selectors trough its selector engine independently. On the other hand `children()` and `andSelf()` are not selector methods (as in involved with the selector engine). `children()` uses DOM methods, and `andSelf()` caching (I guess).

Comment: @Sime: I didn't see your comment, but I agree.  That's why I selected the lonesome's answer.  I'm thinking Chevex is confusing jQuery selectors with CSS selectors; I also think he's biased because he didn't know about the `>`.  Compared to CSS, jQuery's syntax is the same and the outcome is the same, but the methods used are completely different.  CSS is probably more efficient.

Comment: I don't think it has any impact on performance because of the way jquery queue's up it's chains and executes them all at once. I just think it looks cleaner.

Comment: I guess for my actual question it may be shorter, but I'm not sure about cleaner.  I think once you add more filters and are more selective, then having it all in one string would make it a little more messy (eg `$('#foo,#foo div, #foo div span.bar, #foobar div p.foobar, #baz div span div .baz, eg')`).  Combining your `add()` approach with the `children()`s filters would probably best in that circumstance.  IMHO, using the dot notation provides for cleaner code, especially when spanning across multiple lines.

Answer (score 1):

```
var oJQ = $('#foo').children().add('#foo');
```

Comment: Grigory Javadyan's answer is far more succinct. I did not know about the child selector '>', bravo!